# How to do breadth-first search

Tags: java, graph, linked-list

I have implemented a Graph using the hash map linked list and i want to add the Edges containing weight to determine the total cost of travelling from country to country
EX :- UK - Dubai 60000 etc

```
    public class Edge {
    Vertex from;
    Vertex to;
    String al;
    double weight;

    public Edge(Vertex from , Vertex to , String al,double weight)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.al = al;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public void printEdge()
    {
        System.out.println(" FROM : " + from.name + " TO : " + to.name + " AirLine name : |"+al+"| " + "PRICE :- " + weight+"LKR");
    }

}

    public class Vertex {
    String name;
    public Vertex(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

    package GraphTEST;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Graph {

    private Map<Vertex , LinkedHashSet<Vertex>> map = new HashMap<>();

        //Arraylist to store the edges
        public ArrayList<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();

    public void addEdge(Vertex n1 , Vertex n2)
    {
        LinkedHashSet<Vertex> adjacentz = map.get(n1);
        if(adjacentz==null)
        {
            adjacentz = new LinkedHashSet<>();
            map.put(n1, adjacentz);
        }
        adjacentz.add(n2);
    }

        public void addEDGE(Vertex n1, Vertex n2 , String al, double weight)
        {
            Edge e = new Edge(n1, n2, al, weight);
            edges.add(e);


            LinkedHashSet<Vertex> adjacentz = map.get(n1);
        if(adjacentz==null)
        {
            adjacentz = new LinkedHashSet<>();
            map.put(n1, adjacentz);
        }
        adjacentz.add(n2);
        }

        public void printAll()
        {
            for(int i =0;i < edges.size() ;i++)
            {
               edges.get(i).printEdge();
            }
        }
    //------
//  public void twoWayVertex(String n1 , String n2)
//  {
//      addEdge(n1, n2);
//      addEdge(n2, n1);
//  }
    //----------------

    public boolean isConnected(Vertex n1 , Vertex n2)
    {
        Set adjacentt = map.get(n1);
        if(adjacentt==null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return adjacentt.contains(n2);
    }

    public LinkedList<Vertex> adjacentNodesList(Vertex last)
    {
        LinkedHashSet<Vertex> adjacentyy = map.get(last);
        if(adjacentyy==null)
        {
            return new LinkedList<>();
        }
        return new LinkedList<Vertex>(adjacentyy);
    }

}


    package GraphTEST;

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class TestGraph {



    static Vertex EN;
    static Vertex ST;
//starting and ending FROM --> TO
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Graph graph = new Graph();


        Vertex v0 = new Vertex("UK");
        Vertex v1 = new Vertex("USA");
        Vertex v2 = new Vertex("Dubai");
        Vertex v3 = new Vertex("Sri Lanka");
        Vertex v4 = new Vertex("Australia");
        Vertex v5 = new Vertex("Singapore");
        Vertex v6 = new Vertex("Malaysia");
        Vertex v7 = new Vertex("New Zeland");

//  graph.addEdge("UK", "USA");
//  graph.addEdge("USA", "UK");
//  graph.addEdge("UK", "Dubai");
//  graph.addEdge("Dubai", "UK");
//  graph.addEdge("Sri Lanka", "UK");
//  graph.addEdge("Sri Lanka", "USA");
//  graph.addEdge("Dubai", "Sri Lanka");
//  graph.addEdge("Sri Lanka", "Dubai");
//        
//        graph.addEdge("Australia", "Dubai");
//        graph.addEdge("Sri Lanka", "Singapore");
//        graph.addEdge("Singapore ", "Sri Lanka");
//        graph.addEdge("Sri Lanka", "Malaysia");
//        graph.addEdge("Singapore", "Malaysia");
//        graph.addEdge("Singapore", "Australia");
//        graph.addEdge("New Zeland", "Singapore");
//        graph.addEdge("Malaysia", "New Zeland");
//        graph.addEdge("Australia", "New Zeland");
//        graph.addEdge("New Zeland", "Australia");


         ST = v3;
         EN = v0;



        //-----------------------------------------------
       graph.addEDGE(v0, v1, "NG",  35000);
       graph.addEDGE(v1, v0, "NG",  35000);

       graph.addEDGE(v2, v0, "EK",  26000);
       graph.addEDGE(v0, v2, "WK",  26000);

       graph.addEDGE(v3, v0, "UL",  46000);

       graph.addEDGE(v3, v1, "CX",  65000);

       graph.addEDGE(v2, v3, "FD",  20000);
       graph.addEDGE(v3, v2, "FD",  20000);

       graph.addEDGE(v4, v2, "QF",  150000);

       graph.addEDGE(v3, v5, "UL",  20000);
       graph.addEDGE(v5, v3, "UL",  20000);

       graph.addEDGE(v3, v6, "UL",  80000);

       graph.addEDGE(v5, v4, "QF",  110000);

       graph.addEDGE(v5, v6, "MH",  35000);

       graph.addEDGE(v4, v7, "NZ",  43000);
       graph.addEDGE(v7, v4, "NZ",  43000);

       graph.addEDGE(v7, v5, "NZ",  113000);

       graph.addEDGE(v6, v7, "MH",  73000);
       System.out.println("========================================================================");
       graph.printAll();
           System.out.println("========================================================================");
    LinkedList<Vertex> visited = new LinkedList<>();
    visited.add(ST);

    new TestGraph().breadthFirst(graph , visited);

}

public void breadthFirst(Graph graph, LinkedList<Vertex> visited )
{
    LinkedList<Vertex> links = graph.adjacentNodesList(visited.getLast());

    //CHECK 
    for(Vertex Link : links)
    {

        if(visited.contains(Link))
        {
            //System.out.println(" I_N ");
            continue;
        }
        if(Link.equals(EN))
        {
                    System.out.println("****************");
            //System.out.println("IN THE IF");
            visited.add(Link);
                        System.out.println("--");
            printPath(visited);
                        System.out.println("888888888888888888888888");
            visited.removeLast();
            break;
        }
    }
    //in breadth-first recusrsion needs to come after visiting adjacent nodes

    //;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    for (Vertex Link : links) {
        if (visited.contains(Link) || Link.equals(EN)) {
            continue;
        }
        visited.addLast(Link);
        breadthFirst(graph, visited );
        visited.removeLast();
    }
    //;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
}

public void printPath(LinkedList<Vertex> visited)
{

    for(Vertex Link : visited)
    {
        System.out.print(Link.name);
        System.out.print("  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

}
```

This is my code this has four classes 
1) Edge 
2) Vertex
3) Graph
4) TestGraph

in the testGraph class there is the method for the "BreadthfirstSearch" which will out put every possible way to go from one place to another

My task is to make this program  to out put the cost of each path as well

i would appreciate if someone can help me out to do this
Than

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
public void traverseBreadthFirst( Graph graph, Vertex startVertex,
    LinkedList<Vertex> visitedVertices )
{
    LinkedList<Vertex> adjacentVertices = graph.getAdjacentVertices( startVertex );
    for( Vertex visitedVertex : visitedVertices )
    {
        if( adjacentVertices.contains( visitedVertex ) )
            adjacentVertices.remove( visitedVertex );
    }
    for( Vertex adjacentVertex : adjacentVertices )
        visitedVertices.addLast( adjacentVertex );
    for( Vertex adjacentVertex : adjacentVertices )
        breadthFirst( graph, adjacentVertex, visitedVertices );
}
```